# how do I set one variable equal to another in pig latin

Tags: sql, apache-pig

I would like to do

```
register s3n://uw-cse344-code/myudfs.jar
-- load the test file into Pig
--raw = LOAD 's3n://uw-cse344-test/cse344-test-file' USING TextLoader as (line:chararray);
-- later you will load to other files, example:
raw = LOAD 's3n://uw-cse344/btc-2010-chunk-000' USING TextLoader as (line:chararray); 

-- parse each line into ntriples
ntriples = foreach raw generate FLATTEN(myudfs.RDFSplit3(line)) as (subject:chararray,predicate:chararray,object:chararray);

--filter 1
subjects1 = filter ntriples by subject matches '.*rdfabout\\.com.*' PARALLEL 50;
--filter 2
subjects2 = subjects1;
```

but I get the error:

2012-03-10 01:19:18,039 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   mismatched input ';' expecting LEFT_PAREN
Details at logfile: /home/hadoop/pig_1331342327467.log

so it seems pig doesn't like that. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think that kind of 'typical' assignment works in pig. It's not really a programming language in the strict sense - it's a high-level language on top of hadoop with some specialized functions.

i think you'll need to simply re-project the data from subjects1 to subjects2, such as:

```
subjects2 = foreach subjects1 generate $0, $1, $2;
```

another approach might be to use the LIMIT function with some absurdly high parameter.

`subjects2 = subjects2 LIMIT 100000000` ;

there could be a lot of reasons why that doesn't make sense, but it's a thought.

i sense you are considering doing things as you would in a programming language

- i have found that rarely works out like you want it to  but you can always get the job done once you think like Pig.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your example fro DataScience coursera course.
It's strange but I found the same problem. This code works on the on amount of data and don't on the another.

Because we need to change parameters I used this code:

```
filtered2 = foreach filtered generate subject as subject2, predicate as predicate2, object as object2;
```